# how to hide the columns and data in table based on the header and data values by using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two queries for table header and table data so first query is table header I am fetching and second query is table data,my queries are like this,

```
select a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 from test1
select b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 from test2
```

my data like this from those query

```
query1 => $row1[0] = '--HIDE--',$row1[1] = 'fname',$row1[2] = '--HIDE--',$row1[3] = 'lname',$row1[4] = 'address';
query2 => $row2[0] = '',$row2[1] = 'abc',$row2[2] = '',$row2[3] = 'xyz',$row1[4] = '';
```

Table like this:

```
--HIDE--  fname  --HIDE--  lname address
           abc              xyz   
           def              abc
           mno              def
```

Here problem is when the value is `--HIDE--`it should not show that header  and that empty data in my table.
Expected out put is:

```
 fname  lname address
  abc    xyz   
  def    abc
  mno    def
```

Note: In feture that `--HIDE--` column may be have one valid column like city_name or soming that city_name should display in table

Comment: returns select a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 from test1 only one row ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks for your valuble response ,Yes I have one row headers and multiple rows of data like shown in table ,thanks

Comment: are the field names in table2 (test2) are b1,b2 or fname,lname... ??

Comment: @BerndBuffen ``` --HIDE-- ,fname ,--HIDE--, lname address``` are headers comming from table1(test1) and ```b1,b2``` are the column names of table and abc,xyz are the values from table2 (test2)